# Form doesn't submit in chrome if form submit button is disabled onclick

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, yui

I am using YUI3 rich text editor
and onclick of the submit button the editor saves the changes then the button is disabled

```
window.myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor('textarea', myConfig);
    myEditor.render();
    YAHOO.util.Event.on('submitButton', 'click', function() {
        myEditor.saveHTML();
        document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled=true;
    });
```

in firefox everything works fine, editor applies the changes, then the button is disabled then form submits, but in chrome, only the button is disabled and nothing happens
any ideas ?

note: button type is submit.

Comment: Can you confirm that myEditor.saveHTML is working when you *don't* disable the button?

Comment: yes it's working, and it saves the html, and after that i want to disable the button, what not to disable it when that's the requirement ?

Comment: is this related? http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=152f74d4890dc84f&hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked fine after disabling the button then saving the html:

```
window.myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor('textarea', myConfig);
    myEditor.render();
    YAHOO.util.Event.on('submitButton', 'click', function() {
       document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled=true; 
       myEditor.saveHTML();      
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
YAHOO.util.Event.on('submitButton', 'click', function() {
  myEditor.saveHTML();
  setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled=true;
  }, 300);
});
```

Comment: Disable the button 300 milliseconds after clicking it